# Can Let's Kill Krampus still be purchased?

Tags: lets-kill-krampus

I pledged the first Let's Kill Krampus [Kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/lkk/lets-kill-krampus-a-card-game-for-4-9-naughty-chil/posts/567736), which was unfortunately unsuccessful.  I didn't find out about the second Kickstarter until it had already ended, but it was successful, at least.  Recently, someone talking about the upcoming Krampus movie reminded me that LKK exists, so I went looking for it, assuming that it would have entered production after its successful Kickstarter, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Is Let's Kill Krampus available for purchase?

Comment: The answer indicates that the game did exist at some point, so I've created the tag [tag:lets-kill-krumpus]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you need to contact the developers for information.

Based on the last social media post I can find from the company.

> Hi folks, sorry if you couldn't reach us by email, we closed our
>   website and it was linked to our Gmail, so we're figuring out some
>   kinks there. **We are not planning new releases or production runs at
>   this time, but we do have some stock of LKK still available**; we'll
>   post more details soon for anyone interested!

this post was made on facebook December 20, 2014, so they may have already sold out.

https://www.facebook.com/ThreeFatesGames/